# A commutative Banach algebra with an abundance of discountinuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be  the  algebra of all bounded functions from $[0,\;1]$ to  $\mathbb{C}$.

For $f\in A,\;$ $\omega_{f}$ is the  standard [oscillation  function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_oscillation). Each of the following two (equivalent) norms on $A$, defines  a  Banach  algebra  structure on  $A$.

$$\parallel f \parallel=\parallel f\parallel_{\infty}+ \parallel \omega_{f}\parallel_{\infty}$$ or $$\parallel f \parallel=\parallel f\parallel_{\infty}+ \int_{[0,\;1]} \omega_{f}(x)dx$$  The  later is  well defined, since the  oscillation  function is  a bounded measurable function.

**Questions:**

> 1. Let $X$ be the Gelfand spectrum of $A$. What is  the  topological  structure of this  compact nonmetrizable disconnected Haussdorf space, precisely ?   Is it homeomorphic  to a  known  space?
> 2. Assume that $B$ and  $C$ are two $C^{*}$-algebras which are  embedded isometrically into $A$. Must their $C^{*}$-tensor product be embedded in $A$, too?
> 3. Is there a $C^{*}$-norm on $A$ which is equivalent to the above norms? In particular is  $A$, semi-simple?

Comment: Since $\Vert\omega_f\Vert_\infty \leq 2\Vert f\Vert_\infty$, both of the norms $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ that you define above are equivalent to the usual sup norm, and so $A$ is isomorphic as a Banach algebra to $\ell^\infty([0,1])$. Thus for Q1 and Q3 you do not get anything new.

Comment: What is the motivation for Q2?

Comment: @YemonChoi   What is the gelfand  spectrum of $\ell^{\infty}[0,1]$?

Comment: AliTaghavi: if X is any indexing set then $\ell^\infty(X)=C(\beta X_d)$ where $\beta X_d$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$ in its discrete topology.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thanks. So my Q2 is: Assume compact spaces $X$ and  $Y$ are image of $\beta [0,\;1]_{d}$, is their product an image of $\beta [0,\;1]_{d}$ , too?

Comment: Ali, I suggest rewriting the question using topological terms only. No sophisticated language of operator algebras is necessary here.

Comment: @YemonChoi   thank  you very much  for  your  comments

Comment: @TomekKania  and  I thank you, too for  your  comment and  answer. I learned  from comments  and  answer of you two that my  question was really a topological  one. So as  you said, it  is a  good  idea that revise the question to  a topological one. But  before this revision, I have  another question:Let we  have two norm algebra on an  algebra $A$  such that they are  equivalent norm and  we  have two  Banach  algebra  structure. Does this implies that they  are isomorphic  Banach  algebra via  an isometric automorphism? If this  is  not  a trivial question, what is  the  answer about the...

Comment: two norms in my question?I thank you two again@YemonChoi

Comment: @AliTaghavi Consider $\ell^1({\bf Z}/3{\bf Z})$ and ${\bf C}^3$ with $\ell^\infty$-norm. These Banach algebras are isomorphic, but not isometric as Banach spaces.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thank you. By first algebra do you mean $L^{1}(Z/3Z)$ with convloution?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Yes (this was just to get unital examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is an answer to Q2, because as pointed out by Yemon, Q1 and Q3 follow easily from the fact that this algebra is isomorphic to $C(\beta [0,1]_d)$. It is enough to prove then that if two compact spaces $X$ and $Y$ are continuous images of $\beta \kappa$ for some cardinal $\kappa$, then so is $X\times Y$.*

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let $D$ be a dense subset of $X$ endowed with the discrete topology. The identity map

$$\iota\colon D \to X$$

is continuous. By the universal property of the [Stone–Čech functor $\beta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#Universal_property_and_functoriality), $\iota$ extends (uniquely) to a continuous map

$$\beta \iota \colon \beta D \to X.$$
Since continuous images of compact spaces are compact, $\beta \iota$ is surjective. Hence we arrive at the following conclusion.

*Conclusion*. Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space with density character $\kappa$. Then $X$ is a continuous image of $\beta \kappa$. Consequently, since the product of two compact spaces with character $\kappa$ is compact and has density character $\kappa$, if $X$ are $Y$ are continuous, Hausdorff images of $\beta \kappa$, then so is $X\times Y$.

Comment: Hi Tomek, I think in your first line you mean Q1 and Q3.